# My jQuery dropdown menu creates an infinite number of divs

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to create a dropdown menu using jquery. It works...kind-of. I am using a mouseOver call, but every point the mouse hits within the target element, it creates a new div. I want to create one div and just one div when the item is moused over.

```
<div class="site-nav-left">
    <ul class="site-nav-left-list">
        <li class="site-nav-left-item item-0"><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">INQ Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $('.site-nav-link').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).append('<div class="site-top-dropdown"></div>');
        if ($('.site-top-dropdown').parent().hasClass('item-0')) {
            $('.site-top-dropdown').append('<ul class="site-top-down-list"><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">About Me</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Mission</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Media</a></li></ul>')
        }
    });
    $('.site-nav-left-item').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.site-top-dropdown').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Theres a document.ready function in the actual file, and i believe my closings are correct as well in the file. I just dont know how to stop it from creating extra divs after the first one has been created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$('.site-nav-link').mouseover(function () {
    if ($('.site-nav-link').next('.site-top-dropdown').length) {
        $('.site-top-dropdown').remove();
    }
    $(this).after('<div class="site-top-dropdown"></div>');
    if ($('.site-top-dropdown').parent().hasClass('item-0')) {
        $('.site-top-dropdown').append('<ul class="site-top-down-list"><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">About Me</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Mission</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Media</a></li></ul>')
    }
});
$('.site-nav-left-item').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.site-top-dropdown').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-nav-left">
    <ul class="site-nav-left-list">
        <li class="site-nav-left-item item-0"><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">INQ Info</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Use `after()` instead of `append()`,

```
$(this).after('<div class="site-top-dropdown"></div>');
```

`append()` adds the element inside `a`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5du6k7p/1/)

Comment: still can add infinite number of `divs` if you hover really fast without letting it clear.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida added the changes to clear, Ahh, took time to reproduce the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: This is SO CLOSE! With your code, the rate of div creation is drastically decreased. It does, however, create another div if i mouse over the same list item without letting the generated div clear (eg, i mouse over the list item from the created div without hitting any other elements in between). Im thinking its because im nesting my div in the wrong place?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/u5du6k7p/2/. Doesnt create a div now Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use some sort of marker/flag, e.g.:

```
var hovered = 0;

$('.site-nav-link').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="site-top-dropdown"></div>');

    if ($('.site-top-dropdown').parent().hasClass('item-0') && hovered === 0) {
        hovered = 1;
        $('.site-top-dropdown').append('<ul class="site-top-down-list"><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">About Me</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Mission</a></li><li><a href="#" class="site-nav-link">Media</a></li></ul>')
    }
});

$('.site-nav-left-item').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.site-top-dropdown').remove();
    hovered = 0;
});
```